# How to generate Gaussian Noise in Java?

Tags: java

I am looking for a Gaussian Noise generator that takes in 2 parameters: mean and variance, and then generates the Gaussian Noise.

During the searching, I find quite a number of such generators for images. However, what I want is a generic generator. I wish to do something like:

```
myGaussianNoiseGenerator = new GaussianNoiseGenerator(mean, variance);
mySignalWithNoise = mySignal + myGaussianNoiseGenerator.generate();
```

How may I do this?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch, there is no need in overloading `+`. Signal can very well be represented as an array of numbers.

Answer (score 13):

De-normalizing the output of [`Random.nextGaussian()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextGaussian%28%29) to your needs should be straightforward:

```
java.util.Random r = new java.util.Random();
double noise = r.nextGaussian() * Math.sqrt(variance) + mean;
```

Comment: sqrt(variance) ? or simply variance?

Comment: Square root - most of the answers here really want to multiply the output by the standard deviation, which is the square root of the variance.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:
Make a new class first called `GaussianNoiseGenerator`.

```
    public class GaussianNoiseGenerator {

         public final int mean;
         public final int variance;

         public GaussianNoiseGenerator(int mean, int variance) {
          this.mean = mean;
          this.variance = variance;

//do the math here, and return result
int result = this.mean * this.variance;
//I am not sure of the math, just an example for you

return result;
         }
}
```

then you can use it by:

```
GaussianNoiseGenerator myGaussianNoiseGenerator = new GaussianNoiseGenerator(56115, 455445);
```

Comment: I think it is the math OP is asking about.

Comment: Oh, I didn't understand him well x.x

Answer (score 0):

The noise should probably have a mean of 0, so something like this should work:

```
import java.util.Random;
...
Random rand = new Random();
mySignalWithNoise = mySignal + rand.nextGaussian()*noiseStandardDeviation;
```

Answer (score -1):

If by "signal" you mean just double value, then the answer is

```
Random rnd = new Random();
double signal = (rnd.nextGaussian() - mean) / Math.sqrt(variance);
```

Where [`Random`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) is standard class.

**Proof**

If you group sigma and mu under square with x here

Factor before exponent is irrelevant since distribution can be renormalized.

[image]

Comment: variance or standard deviation please?

Comment: This looks wrong. `nextGaussian` generates numbers from N(0, 1), so actually it should be like this: `signal = rnd.nextGaussian() * stdDev + mean`, where `stdDev = Math.sqrt(variance)`. Correct me if I'm wrong.